# Passing database connections to a sub routine or create a new one?

Tags: perl

should I pass an open database connection to all my used sub routines?

```
my $dbh = MysqlConnect();
my $title = GetTitle($id, $dbh);
my $price = GetPrice($id, $dbh);
my $author = GetAuthor($id, $dbh);
MysqlDisconnect($dbh);

sub GetTitle {
my $id = shift;
my dbh = shift;
.... # get title from database
}
sub GetPrice {...}
sub GetAuthor {...}
```

Or should I open a new connection in every sub routine I use?

```
my $title = GetTitle($id);
my $price = GetPrice($id);
my $author = GetAuthor($id);

sub GetTitle {
my $id = shift;
my $dbh = MysqlConnect();
.... # get title from database
MysqlDisconnect($dbh);
}
sub GetPrice {...}
sub GetAuthor {...}
```

Sincerly
Jan

Comment: I would write `my ( $title, $price, $author ) = GetInfo($dbh, $id)`
`

Answer (score 1):

There is overhead in opening database connections, so you should reuse your connection as much as you can.

The major exception to this rule would be if your subroutines forked a new process or ran in a new thread. It is generally not safe to reuse the same handle in different processes or threads, so you should create a new connection for each process and thread.

Answer (score 1):

I would fetch all of the information in one `SELECT`, like this

```
sub get_info {
    my ($dbh, $id) = @_;

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT title, price, author FROM table WHERE id = ?');
    $sth->execute($id);
    $sth->fetchrow_array;
}

my ( $title, $price, $author ) = GetInfo($dbh, $id);
```

Or, better still, fetch a hash of everything in the table and pick out the parts you need

```
sub get_info_hash {
    my ($dbh, $id) = @_;

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?');
    $sth->execute($id);
    $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
}

my $info = get_info_hash($dbh, $id);
my ( $title, $price, $author ) = @{$info}{qw/ title price author /};
```

The prevailing naming standard for Perl code is to use `snake_case` for lexical variables, and capital letters for globals

It would be better to avoid repeating the `prepare` every time, and do it only once, the first time it is needed. That lends itself better to an object-oriented approach where disconnecting the database also invalidates all the cached statement handles, but if the database handle is never likely to be disconnected then a simple closure will suffice

```
{
    my $sth;

    sub get_info_hash {
        my ($dbh, $id) = @_;

        $sth //= $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?');
        $sth->execute($id);
        $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
    }
}

my $info = get_info_hash($dbh, $id);
my ( $title, $price, $author ) = @{$info}{qw/ title price author /};
```

Note that you will want to add some error handling to any of these options

Comment: @simbabque: I would be all over `state` if it provided for aggregate data. As it stands it provides what I want very rarely.

Comment: Was just an example with getting title, author and price.

Comment: @JanB: I guessed as much. That's why I suggested that you write `get_info_hash` to return a hash containing all of the columns by name. It won't be significantly slower than fetching just the columns that you need, and you will never need to rewrite it even if requirements change.